# statically allocated variables given memory at runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

This problem has been bugging me for quite a while now.

```
int n;
cin>>n;

if(n is even) {
char c;
cout<<"character created";
}

else {
double d;
cout<<"double created";
}
```

now if the inputted number is even then a double will be created else a character will be created. The value of n is given at runtime, so the memory is allocated to double/char at runtime. But aren't only dynamically created variables allocated memory at runtime?

Comment: These are *automatic* storage variables. Not static.

Comment: This is neither valid C nor C++.

Comment: These aren't static variables. They would need the keyword `static` in order to be so. And if they were defined as `static`, then they would be allocated some memory before runtime. Of course, they would also go out of scope without ever being used (given the example code)

Comment: Both `c` and `d` fall out of scope before being used. They're irrelevant in this code.